# Still stuck on simplifying terms while doing linear combinations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, euclidean-algorithm

So I'm currently trying to wrap my head around finding gcd through the Euclidean Algorithm in order to write the integers as a linear combination.

For example, a problem is to express the gcd(9999,11111) as a linear combination of these integers.

> 11111 = 9999 * 1 + 1112
>
> 9999 = 1112 * 8 + 1103
>
> 1112 = 1103 * 1 + 9
>
> 9 = 5 * 1 + 4
>
> 5 = 4 * 1 + 1

So gcd(11111,9999) = 1.

Going back, it's time to rewrite the equations as an expression of the remainder.

> 1112 = 11111 - 9999
>
> 1103 = 9999 - 1112 * 8
>
> 9 = 1112 - 1103
>
> 5 = 1103 - 122 * 9
>
> 4 = 9 -5
>
> 1 = 5 -4

Then, as I understand it, you work your way up and substitute.

> 1 = 5 - 4
>
> 1 = 5 - (9 - 5) = ?

My problem is, I don't understand how to simplify. That's as far as I've got. How to do this?!

Comment: Have a look at the questions listed under "Related" on this page to see whether one or another answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error at the last but one line: you should divide $1103$ by $9$, not $9$ by $5$.

The systematic way consists in using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, which gives Bézout's coefficients for every remainder in the Euclidean Algorithm:

$$ \begin{array}{rrrr}
   r_i  & u_i & v_i & q_i\\
   \hline
 11111 & 1 & 0 & \\
  9999 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
     \hline
 1103 & -8 & 9 & 1\\
 9 & 9 & -10 & 122 \\
5 & -1106 & 1229 & 1 \\
 4 & 1115 & -1239 & 1\\
 1 & -2221 & 2468 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Thus $1=2468\times 9999-2221\times11111$.

Comment: Thanks for that! I realize what I was thinking wrong and I've got the hang of it now. I appreciate it. Great answer.